# How to extract text from PDF in React native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, pdf

I want to extract text from the pdf file I selected in React native. Although I tried many ways like pdf2Json, pdf parse, they all contain errors. All running with node and giving fs error.

for pdf parse, MyCode:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const parser = require("pdf-parse");

const file = fs.readFile("./sample.pdf");

parser(file).then(function (data) {
  console.log(data.text);
 });
```

It works when I run my code as node Parser.js, but I can't use it in react native. How can I run this code with a button onpress? Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when you realize there's no one there :c